# Reduction meta-operator inconsistency

Tags: operators, reduce, meta, raku

When we examine the reduce function:

```
    my $result = reduce &reduction_procedure, @array;
```

we conclude with the following simple rules to the inner workings:

```
    Reduction Rules
    ---------------
    1. For the first pair of objects from our input (@array)
       we apply the reduction procedure (&reduction_procedure) and we get our first result.

    2. We apply the reduction procedure (&reduction_procedure) to the result (object)
       of the previous rule and the next input (object) from our input (@array),
       and we get an intermediate result (object).

    3. We run rule.2 for every of the remaining objects from our input (@array)
```

This simple rules work also the same for the reduction metaoperator []. For example:

```
    example.1
    ---------
    say [+] [1,2,3,4]; # result : 10
```

For example.1 the reduction rules apply as is:

```
    Step.1 use Rule.1 : 1 + 2 = 3     1(first value)     + 2(second value)  = 3
    Step.2 use Rule.2 : 3 + 3 = 6     3(previous result) + 3(current value) = 6
    Step.3 use Rule.2 : 6 + 4 = 10    6(previous result) + 4(current value) = 10
```

but NOT for the following example:

```
    example.2
    ----------
    say [<] 1,2,3,4;   # result : True
```

For example.2 we observe an inconsistency:

```
    Step.1 use Rule.1 : 1 < 2 = True    1(first value)         <  2(second value)      = True
    Step.2 use Rule.2 : 2 < 3 = True    True(previous result) &&  True(current result) = True
    Step.3 use Rule.2 : 3 < 4 = True    True(previous result) &&  True(current result) = True(result)
```

The inconsistency is that from Step.2 and onwards we can NOT use the result of the previous step as the first parameter of subsequent reduce operations,
but instead we calculate a logical intermediate result, with use of the actual values and finally we add as a final step the use of "logical AND" upon 
the intermediate logical results of each step:

```
    Reduction Result = True && True && True = True (use of logical AND as "meta-reduction" operator)
```

Sort of speak we have a "meta-reduction" metaoperator!

Questions:

```
    1. Is that an inconsistency with a purpose?

    2. Can we exploit this behavior? For instance instead of use of && (logical AND)
       as "meta-reduction" operator can we use || (logical OR) or ?^ (logical XOR) ?
```

Comment: BTW, with the reduction metaoperator you can precede the operator with a backslash to get the reduction's intermediate values (e.g., `say [\+] [1,2,3,4];` outputs `(1 3 6 10)`).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is not an inconsistency but and example of how [operator associativity](https://docs.raku.org/language/functions#Associativity) works in Raku.

Writing :

```
[<] 1,2,3,4
```

Is the same as writing :

```
1 < 2 < 3 < 4
```

In most languages this wouldn't work but the < operator has chain associativity so it effectively treats this as :

```
(1 < 2) and (2 < 3) and (3 < 4)
```

Which is True.

Comment: In the following example code the "foo" operator has "chain" associativity but it behaves NOT as I expected:
 
 sub infix:<foo>(Int $a, Int $b --> Bool) is assoc<chain> {
  my $p = ($a, $b).pick;
  
  $p.so
 }
 
 say 'Result: ' ~ [foo] 0,1,0,0;
`code`
Resolving the flow of execution:
 [foo] 0,1,0,0

Is the same as writing :

 0 foo 1 foo 0 foo 0

the foo operator has chain associativity so it must effectively treat this as :

 (0 foo 1) and (1 foo 0) and (0 foo 0)

so it must be always False but this is NOT the case!

I am a bit confused!

Comment: If you want to create your own chaining operator you need a version that accepts a slurpy array of values and then knows how to handle that.

Comment: Can you give an exampe of a custom chain associative operator?

Comment: I'm doing some further investigation into this. I think the build in chain ops have some special magic applied that user generated ones don't get. 
But you *can* define a List Op and deal with them that way.

Comment: https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/3370 : Raised an issue about user generated Chaining operators.

Comment: Also note that the standard chain operators do all work as expeced, it's just custom ones that don't :(

Comment: Yes I've noticed! Probably a bug! Let's see the outcome of your raised issue.

Comment: @jakar I believe the most recent Rakudo release includes the this for this issue :)